# Python цикл for для двух диапазонов

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Имеются две диапазонные переменные А и В есть ли возможность организовать цикл таким образом чтобы он проходил по этим диапазонам и чтобы все работало одним циклом. Пока реализовал двумя циклами.

```py
A = range(0,181,1)
B = range(180,-1,-1)

for x in A :
    print(x)

for x in B:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Если нужен последовательный, а не параллельный обход, воспользуйтесь [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) `for x in itertools.chain(A, B): ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для прохода по двум итерируемым объектам (спискам, диапазонам и т.д.) параллельно используется функция `zip` (на английском zip-locker - это застежка-молния, получается что две или больше последовательности как бы "застегиваются" вместе):

```
A = range(0,181,1)
B = range(180,-1,-1)

for x, y in zip(A, B):
    print(x, y)
```

Цикл закончится когда завершится более короткий итерируемый объект. Если нужно выполнять цикл пока не завершится самый длинный объект, есть функция `zip_longest` из стандартного модуля `itertools`.