# Объединение двух числовых списков python по определенному принципу

Tags: python

Нужно объединить два числовых списка. Нужно их объединить по принципу а[1,1] b[2,2], а и b [1,2,1,2]. Помогите оптимизировать код в функции.

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
b = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
def combine_lists(a, b):
​ ​ ​ ​ len_a = len(a)
​ ​ ​ ​ len_b = len(b)
​ ​ ​ ​ if len_a < len_b:
​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ limit = len_a
​ ​ ​ ​ else:
​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ limit = len_b
​ ​ ​ ​ i = 0
​ ​ ​ ​ r = []
​ ​ ​ ​ while i < limit:
​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ r.append(a[i])
​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ r.append(b[i])
​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ i += 1
​ ​ ​ ​ return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
​ ​ ​ ​
​ ​ ​ ​ print(repr(combine_lists(a, b)))
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049653/python-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2